# Why does the IF statement does not work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this code basically get some check radio of a form and then make send into a php file, the code its fine but im only have a doubt on the conditional part:

**Html code:**

```
<div id="content0">
<h1>Paso 1)</h1>
<p align="left"></p>
<h2>¿Cuantos procesos desea Ingresar/Consultar?</h2>
<br>
<!-- <label>Escoge un número</label> -->
<form name="form_data" id="form_data">  
    1 <input name="ciudad" value="1" type="radio">  
    2 <input name="ciudad" value="2" type="radio"> 
    3 <input name="ciudad" value="3"  type="radio"> 
    4 <input name="ciudad" value="4" type="radio"> <br>
    5 <input name="ciudad" value="5" type="radio">
    6 <input name="ciudad" value="6" type="radio">
    7 <input name="ciudad" value="7" type="radio">
    8 <input name="ciudad" value="8" type="radio"> <br>
    9 <input name="ciudad" value="9" type="radio">
    10 <input name="ciudad" value="10" type="radio"> <br>
    <input value="Enviar" id="btn_enviar0" href="javascript:toggle() </input> <br /> <br />      
    <label id=" mensaje="" type="button"> </form>
    <div id="resultado"></div>
</div>

<div id="content4" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Paso 5)</h1>
</div>
```

**Js code:**

```
function getRadioValue() 
{
    for (index=0; index < document.form_data.ciudad.length; index++) 
    {
        if (document.form_data.ciudad[index].checked) 
        {
            var radioValue =form_data.ciudad[index].value;
            var num2=parseInt(radioValue);
            break;
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#btn_enviar').click(function()
    {
        if( validaText( 'name1','Nombre' ) == false) 
            return false;
        if( validaText( 'name2','Nombre' ) == false) 
            return false;
        if( validaSelect( 'select_especialidad','Especialidad' ) == false) 
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url :'upload4.php',
            data: $('#form_data4').serialize(),
            beforeSend : function()
            {
                $('#mensaje4').html('Enviando datos...');
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                $('#mensaje4').html('Datos enviados correctamente.');
                $('#resultado4').html(data);    
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                $('#form_data4').slideUp();
                $('#resultado4').slideDown();
                $('#flecha4').show();
                getRadioValue();
                if (num2>=3)
                    $('#content4').show();
            }
        });
    }); 

    $('#regresar').click(function()
    {
        $('#form_data')[0].reset();
        $('#form_data').slideDown();
        $('#resultado').slideUp();
        $('#mensaje').html('');
    });
});

function validaText(texto,salida)
{
    if($('#'+texto).val()=="")
    {
        alert('Em campo '+salida+' es requerido.');
        $('#'+texto).focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function validaSelect(select,salida)
{
    if($('#'+select).val()==0)
    {
        alert('Seleccione '+salida);
        return false;
    }   
}
```

I don't know much about javascript (I make my codes with php but im learning), but.. why this part of the code don't work?

```
if (num2>=3)
{
    $('#content4').show();
}
```

Comment: why do you have a break at the end of the getReadioValue function

Comment: Learn to use a javascript console and make a step by step debug. I recomend firebug which is available to firefox.

Comment: I'm a newbie on javascript @zero :P

Comment: Yeah, chrome has one built, just press Ctrl + shift + i and you can see the console. Now go ahead and type `$("body").css("opacity", "0.5");` Or whatever you like. Also, read a javascript book, and watch some stuff on youtube, Douglas Crockford's talks are a fine start.

Comment: @Roger I have some problems because my native language its php so I found javascript a little disordered or is my impression.

Comment: All the more reason to follow Roger's advice by checking out some resources that will help you learn JavaScript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
function getRadioValue() {
        for (index=0; index < document.form_data.ciudad.length; index++) {
            if (document.form_data.ciudad[index].checked) {
                var radioValue =form_data.ciudad[index].value;
                 return parseInt(radioValue); //<--- Change1
            }
        }
    }
```

...

```
     complete: function(){
         $('#form_data4').slideUp();
         $('#resultado4').slideDown();
          $('#flecha4').show();
            var num2 = getRadioValue();  //<-- Change 2
          if (num2>=3)
```

In your code the **scope** of the variable **num2** is within the function **getRadioValue**, as you have declared in there